# Checking with Python3 if ZIP is installed on OS (Terminal)

Tags: python-3.x, operating-system, zip

I try to work through Byte of Python3 and there is an example script for backing up folders and creating a zip file.

I would like the script to check if zip is available within the os (Windows, Linux, Mac). Is there a way you can do this?

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

You could check using the zipfile module.
It will check for everything that is needed to run. If the OS version of zip is missing the import of the module will either fail (because it's missing) or the module works without the OS version (which should be fine too).

I can't think of any other easy, portable approach. On UNIX systems you could just check if "zip" is found in the PATH but on windows it's not guaranteed that it is in the PATH.